# Reset pyqtgraph timer

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I'm trying to reset the timer of pyqtgraph, but I'm not doing it correctly.

This is the plot widget.

```
 self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
```

This is the timer.

```
self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
```

How I start it.

```
self.timer.setInterval(50)
self.timer.start()
```

And this is the way how I try to reset,but not working. Because when I start again like above
it will start the plot in the same time I tried to reset.

```
self.timer.stop() 
self.graphWidget.clear()
```

Does anyone know any way to do this correctly ? I'm using PyQt6 if it help's.

Comment: maybe create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  so we could simply copy and run it - to test problem